# Would you use distinct, or maybe a window function to do this?

Tags: postgresql

Is there someway to shortcut it? window function? Group by? Or is distinct the right approach?

```
select
     distinct itemid item_id
    from
        unitactuals.unitserials
    where
        mfgdate > $begin_date_range
        and mfgdate < $end_date_range
        and siteid = $site_id
        and serial like ($serial_prefix || '%')
```

Comment: I can't imagine anything more simple than what you've already written. You want distinct `itemid` where these conditions hit. This is how you write that.

Comment: What do you mean by "shortcut it"? Golf your SQL, i.e. write the same query in less characters?

Comment: like a max(mfgdate) group by itemid or some such.

Comment: Adding gratuitous complexity is unlikely to be faster, but you could race your horses and see who wins.  Making sure your indexes and (possibly) partitioning are suitable should be the first thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no better option than `DISTINCT` if you need to avoid duplicate results.

If the `DISTINCT` really is what makes that query slow, the only thing you can do is to set `work_mem` as high as you can for this query.

If `DISTINCT` is not the bottleneck, perhaps you can add indexes to speed up the query.

First, I would rewrite the query to use the [string prefix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT itemid item_id
FROM unitactuals.unitserials
WHERE mfgdate > $begin_date_range
  AND mfgdate < $end_date_range
  AND siteid = $site_id
  AND serial ^@ $serial_prefix;
```

Then these two indexes might speed up the query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON unitactuals.unitserials (siteid, mfgdate);
CREATE INDEX ON unitactuals.unitserials USING spgist (serial);
```

Comment: Is there a list of string prefix operators? I found this mention --
   
" Also see the prefix operator ^@ and corresponding starts_with function, which are useful in cases where simply matching the beginning of a string is needed. " 
   
From here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

Comment: That's the only one. But you are right, it is severely underdocumented.

Comment: I see now that this shortcoming was fixed in v15. I have added a link to the documentation.

Comment: is the ^@ (starts_with) any faster for a parameterized query? Or just a preference over the like syntax?

Comment: A `LIKE` query that does not have a constant on the right side will never use a B-tree index.

Comment: wonderful, thanks again for taking the time!